# Does topological closure operator distribute over set difference?

Tags: general-topology

Consider tw0 sets $A, B$ from the topological space X.
Is the following true:
$$
\mathbb{cl} (A \setminus B) = \mathbb{cl}\, A  \setminus \mathbb{cl} \,B
$$

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, let $A$ be a closed and $B$ a single point which belongs to $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the rationals, $B$ the irrationals in $\Bbb R$ usual topology.

$A \setminus B = \Bbb Q$ with closure $\Bbb R$

however, both the closure of $A$ and $B$ are $\Bbb R$ so the right hand side is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you aware of a formula? I couldn't find so far.

Comment: @user48672 there is none AFAIK. One inclusion does always hold.